# Should I delete my account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I only asked one question so far, and it got deleted by community. But not as spam or offensive. Since there is nothing lit about my current profile here, is it a good idea to suicide and recreate my account if needed?

Answer (score 6):

No, do not delete your account.

Your post was automatically deleted.  The system automatically deletes inactive, unanswered questions after one month if negatively scored or after one year if zero-scored.  For the technical details, see:

[Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

I've had a look at the question you asked early 2019.  It looks like it wasn't very well received by the community, but don't feel discouraged.  We've had much, much worse questions.  I am not a geologist, so I'm not in the best position to recommend specifically how to improve it, but perhaps it would help to define more specifically what exactly you are looking for, to make sure the question is well-defined and scientifically answerable.

Feel free to ask your question again and/or ask for help here on meta on how to improve your question.